# Create a user passing in a json of user object (Microsoft Graph)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a user by calling microsoft graph and passing in a json string (one that looks like a user object) into the req.body of a httprequest.
The steps I am currently following are:

1. Call microsoft graph to get the user's properties
2. Serialize content into a json string (jsonString) and pass it in as the req.Body of a HTTPRequest when using a graph call to create a user in azure active directory

When I pass the content into the req.Body, since there are required fields that must be filled out (accountEnabled, displayName, onPremisesImmutableId, password, etc.), it will not be created cause it does not specify the required field (ex: In the content of jsonString, password is set to null. Password would need to have a value).

The source link of the graph call is found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Is there a way to pass in my jsonString and also specify some of the user properties within the req.Body? If not, is there a workaround?

`var createUser = await httpClient.PostAsync(link, "Token", jsonString);`

Answer (score 0):

It's important that you cannot retrieve the password for any user in Azure AD in any way.
So, you need to set the value of the password in your code.

The other properties(displayName, MailNickname, UserPrincipalName, etc.) could be set directly, see：

[image]

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

User user = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].Request().GetAsync();

var newUser = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
    MailNickname = user.MailNickname,
    UserPrincipalName = user.UserPrincipalName,
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = "password-value"
    }
};

await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(newUser);
```

I refer to the code with C# in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: By setting the values above, would only those values be specified? All of the other properties will be shown as null if not set?

Comment: It is just an example to create user, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-1-create-a-user). You could change the properties to what you would like. The properties will be set as null or the default value if not set.